# interface conversion: interface{} is nil, not bool

Tags: go, go-gin

I'm relatively new to Go.

I'm making changes to an existing project.
I need to retrieve an element's value that might be present in an HTTP request's body and pop it.

```
var returnValues = body.Params["returnValues"].(bool)
delete(body.Params, "returnValues")
```

I'm getting error at first line.

> interface conversion: interface {} is nil, not bool

Sample body:

```
{
"Params": {
    "returnValues": true
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any json struct or something to decode in your code? Where you unmarshal your request body to Go object?

Comment: That means `body.Params` map does not have `returnValues` key, or it has it but it is nil. How do you construct `body.Params`?

Comment: *"I need to retrieve an element's value that **might be present** in an HTTP request's body and pop it."* -- Well you're getting the error because it **is not present**. You should *never* do `var v = x.(bool)` unless you are certain that `x` contains a `bool` value. If there are cases where it may not be `bool` then your program will crash when it encounters those cases. If you want to avoid the crash, use the "comma ok" idiom, e.g. `var v, ok = x.(bool)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always if you access a map of interfaces or default nil types and do things using that map, make sure that value for the key is existing in the map before use it. If that value is not exist in the map, it will return nil and panic with nil reference.

```
r, ok := body.Params["returnValues"]
    if !ok {
        // returnValues not present in Params map. Handle the scenario
        // and don't continue below 
    }
    var returnValues = r.(bool)
    delete(body.Params, "returnValues")
```

And also if you are not sure about the variable type you are accessing, then use type assertion and see whether your type is ok or not. Then if it is null, then it also return false for the type assertion.

```
returnValues, ok := body.Params["returnValues"].(bool)
    if !ok {
        // returnValues may not present in Params map. or it is not an 
        // boolean type, handle scenario here
    }
    delete(body.Params, "returnValues")
```

Comment: This may still fail, horribly. Rather then using the "comma ok" idiom on the map read, in this case, you should use it on the type assertion.

Comment: Yeah that also a better option. I will add that also.